# LCD Screen distorted by vertical black lines

Tags: laptop, lcd, distortion

They say a picture is worth a thousand words.

The following is supposed to show a completely white display:

[image: display]

Notice the vertical lines? And no, it's not caused just by my digital camera. Although it does seem to add to it.

I believe this problem started when I cracked my laptop's original screen, but left the laptop running regardless (with the broken screen attached). I have now replaced said display, but the vertical lines are still there on the new display.

What would cause my screen to be covered in black vertical lines like this?

Comment: Have you double-checked for proper screen and cable installs?  Perhaps the LCD panel wasn't the only thing to break when you cracked the screen.. If you plug in an external monitor, does it display the lines as well?

Comment: I replaced the LCD cable today, but that didn't fix it either. An external monitor works fine on the HDMI port. Would it be any different for VGA?

Comment: Could be, but I wouldn't bet on it if HDMI looks OK.  Did you get an exact, specific replacement when you got the panel?  Perhaps a connector (for said new cable) got damaged along the way? Hard to say without seeing it. hopfully someone else can come along and just know. but I doubt it, and if I was doing that in the shop, after double-checking fitment and connections, I'd be ordering a new panel to determine if the new one was defective or not.

Comment: Does it help if I say that the cracked panel started showing the same lines before I finally removed it? That's what worries me most.

Comment: Then yup, it's something OTHER than the panel then.  Perhaps the graphics adapter itself?  Again, hard to say, since you physically damaged it somehow, just about anything could be broken.. :(